# Data folder location in multi-user environment in Android 4.2

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Call of **Environment.getDataDirectory()** returns same info (**/data**) when I run my app from under different users. However the databases my application use in fact are different. I used **SQLiteOpenHelper** for creating and accessing databases in internal memory.

I can access database file directly from the first user using this path:
**/data/app_package_name/databases/database_file.db**

From the second user I got **permission denied** error. Obviously I tried to access db in other user environment.

So what is the real location of the database for the second user? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().replace("files", "databases") + File.separator + DB_NAME
```